# Extracting specific strings from data with MID in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm really having problems writing a MID formula to extract the due date (always the same length) and Row count (variable length). Could anybody help me please? I'm getting a little lost with nested formulas.

Project in Batch 100 of 120 for A2B_1414696641872. Due date: **2014-11-03**. Word count: 1976. Row count: **345**.

Strings in column A, column B should contain 2014-11-03 and column C should contain 345

Project in Batch 10 of 12 for A2B_141469664. Due date: **2014-11-03**. Word count: 19. Row count: **3**.

Strings in column A, column B should contain 2014-11-03 and column C should contain 19

--

I currently have the following for extracting the due date (it works):

```
=MID(LEFT(B1,FIND(". Word count",B1)-1),FIND("Due date:",B1)+10,LEN(B1))
```

Comment: What do you have right now?

Comment: Hi Jerry. Thanks for replying. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things a little with the formula that you have right now. I would suggest the following for the date:

```
=MID(B1,FIND("Due date:",B1)+10,10)
```

`Due Date:` has a length of 9, so since we are `FIND`ing it, you need to add 10 to it (1 more to get the first character of the date).

Then the date is always 10 characters long: `yyyy-mm-dd` so you can use 10 for the date.

For the row count, it's similar, and I suggest using `Row count:` to get it:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Row count:",A1)+11,1000)
```

And I just used a really big value for the length because the row count is at the end, and taking a value higher than the actual length doesn't hurt here.

---

EDIT: Missed the period. For that, I would suggest removing the dots first:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),FIND("Row count:",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+11,10)
```

Comment: Of course! I got so wrapped up in knowing that the row count was variable that I accounted for that for the due date needlessly. I like your solution for the row count, but would you be able edit it so that it trims the leading space and the trailing period? Thanks so much for your speedy reply! | Edit: I've changed 11 to 12 to remove the space. Could a Right function be used to remove the period?

Comment: @user3842077 Oh, I missed the period...  Edited it in. As for the trimming, I'm not sure how you are having spaces if there are single spaces in the data, but you can either change the numbers or use an outer `TRIM( ... )` to the formula.

Comment: The following removes the extra dot / period: =RIGHT(MID(A1,FIND("Asin count: ",A1,1)+LEN("Asin count: "),LEN(A1)-(FIND("Asin count: ",A1,1)+LEN("Row count: "))))-1

Answer (score 0):

Cell A1 (to contain the string under test):

```
Project in Batch 100 of 120 for A2B_1414696641872. Due date: 2014-11-03. Word count: 1976. Row count: 345.
```

Cell B1:

```
=MID( A1,
      FIND("Due date: ",A1,1) + LEN("Due date: "),
      10
     )
```

Cell C1:

```
=MID( A1,    
      FIND("Row count: ",A1,1) + LEN("Row count: "),      
      LEN(A1) -   (FIND("Row count: ",A1,1) + LEN("Row count: ")   - 1  ) 
     )
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method.  For the Due Date:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("????-??-??",A1,SEARCH("Due Date",A1)),10)
```

or, it there will be only a single date in the string

=MID(A1,SEARCH("????-??-??",A1),10)

For the Row count, if it will always be at the end:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),".","")
```